# Second order homogeneous ordinary differential equation with variable coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation,
\begin{equation}
y^{''}_{xx} + a_1 x y^{'}_{x} +(a_0x+b_0)y=0
\end{equation}
This equation is not the Cauchy‐Euler Equidimensional. I found a solution to the following differntial equation in Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations by Andrei Polyanin and Valentin Zaitsev,
 \begin{equation}
 (ax_2+b2) y^{''}_{xx} + (a_1 x +b_1) y^{'}_{x} + (a_0 x + b_0) y=0
 \end{equation}
The equation that I am trying to solve is special case of the prevous equation ($a_2=b_10, b_2=1$). The solution to this equation is 
\begin{equation}
y=e^{hx} z(\zeta), where \, \zeta=\dfrac{x-\mu}{\lambda}
\end{equation} 
The authors mentioned that $z(\zeta)$ matches $\mathcal{L}(a,b;x)$ arbitrary solution of the degenerate hyperheometric equation $x y^{''}_{xx}+ (b-x) y^{'}_{x} -ay=0$, yet it is not clear how to do that. I have attached four pages of the [books](https://app.box.com/s/b7bdwjx7iztgnkm4wjpihch04ic1wmcn) that refere to that solution. The problem is number 103.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you mixing two notations for derivative?  Does $y''_{xx}$ just mean $y''$ (where the independent variable is $x$)?

Comment: Yet, they are the same. I just follow the notation in the Andrei Polyanin and Valentin Zaitsev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Maple, your DE has general solution
$$ y \left( x \right) =c_1 {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {a_{{0}}x}{a_{{1}}}}}}  {
{ U}\left({\frac {b_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+{a_{{0}}}^{2}}{2\,{a_{{1}}}^
{3}}},\,{\frac{1}{2}},\,-{\frac { \left( x{a_{{1}}}^{2}-2\,a_{{0}}
 \right) ^{2}}{2\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}}}\right)}+ c_2{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {a_{{0}}x}{a_{{1}}}}}}  {{ M}\left({\frac 
{b_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+{a_{{0}}}^{2}}{2\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}}},\,{\frac{1}{2}
},\,-{\frac { \left( x{a_{{1}}}^{2}-2\,a_{{0}} \right) ^{2}}{2\,{a_{{1
}}}^{3}}}\right)}
$$
where $U$ and $M$ are Kummer functions.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I am wondering if the general solution is just a repetitive of the same terms. $U$ and $M$ look identical.

Comment: $U$ and $M$ are quite different.  $M(p, 1/2, t) = 1 + 2 p t + \ldots$ while $U(p,1/2,t) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(p+1/2)} - \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(p)} \sqrt{t} + \ldots$.