# Series of Kummer function works only with the third variable.

Tags: special-functions, math-software, maple

I am using Maple software to find the series of KummerU function (Kummer function of the second kind).

I found that `series(KummerU(p,1/2,t),t)` works as below, but `series(KummerU(p,1/2,t),p)` gives me the following error:
 *Error in (series/fracpower) unable to compute series*.

This is a follow up on this question [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591104/second-order-homogeneous-ordinary-differential-equation-with-variable-coefficien/3591120?noredirect=1#comment7384068_3591120)

[image: link]

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details! E.g., what software are you using?

Comment: I am using Maple.

Comment: I do not think there is a nice series in powers of $p$. Do you want to compute the function for small $p$ or large $p$?

Comment: I am not sure how you define small vs. large $p$ in that context.

Comment: There are asymptotic expansions for this function which are useful when $p$ is large, $p=100$ or $1000$ say.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I am confused about the behavior of the maple function series. I am not sure why it works with $t$ and not $p$.  Is that something about the series function itself or just because of other property of the Kummer functions.

Comment: Obtaining the series in terms of $t$ is easy by combining http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42 with http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E2 It is known that the $M$ function is entire in its first parameter so you can try expanding that function instead and then use http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42 with http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E2

Comment: Thanks, I see what you saying. I tried to do that, and then I compared what I did with the  Maple series function. I newbie to Maple. So I am not sure If I am using it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you could have more than
$$U\left(p,\frac{1}{2},t\right)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{U^{(n,0,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2},t\right)}{n!} p^n$$ except if $t=0$.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, but why it works only with ```series(KummerU(p,1/2,t),t)``` and not ```series(KummerU(p,1/2,t),p)```